# Cantor Normal form and the steps taken

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a question regarding cantor normal form, and the steps in putting certain questions into this form, my Prof. gave me one hand out and then a bunch of questions and i cannot figure them out exactly

> Prove that $(\omega+1)\omega=\omega^2$

So far I have

$$\begin{align*}
(\omega+1)\omega &= \mathrm{ord}\Bigl(\mathbb{N} \times(\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\})\Bigr)\\
\omega\omega&=\mathrm{ord}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})(i,j)\text{ if }i=1,j\neq\infty\\
(i,j) &\longmapsto\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(i+1,1) &\text{if }j=\infty\\
(i,j+1) &\text{if }i\neq 1, j\neq\infty
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}$$

Is this right? any corrections would be very helpful my stepwise cantor normal form is struggling because of my lack of information on the topic...

two other questions i cannot figure out are

- write in cantor normal form - $(\omega+1)^2$
- prove  $(\omega+1)^{\omega}=\omega^{\omega}$

any answers for these or help would be appreciated, also any advice on understanding putting these in cantor normal form or the steps involved would help tremendously.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you study any ordinal arithmetics?

Comment: yes I did, addition, multiplication, exponentiation,

Comment: but im not sure how it applies to cantor normal form, im a little confused by the steps taken in examples i've seen, and these ones are due for homework and i am a little lost to say the least

Comment: the last one i find most difficult whre you have to prove it is equal to w^w

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Cantor normal form of an ordinal is essentially a finite polynomial in $\omega$ over the ordinals.

But first let us recall the definition of addition, multiplication and exponentiation at limit points,

Suppose $\beta$ is a limit ordinal and $\alpha$ is an ordinal then:

- $\alpha + \beta = \sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid \gamma<\beta\}$
- $\alpha\cdot\beta = \sup\{\alpha\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$
- $\alpha^\beta = \sup\{\alpha^\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$.

Note that we can restrict ourselves to any unbounded subset of $\beta$, which allows some degree of freedom when calculating ordinal arithmetic at limit stages.

Now for calculating the Cantor normal form, first we want to calculate the ordinal itself, then we can decompose it to its CNF.

$(\omega+1)\cdot\omega = \sup\{(\omega+1)\cdot n\mid n<\omega\} = \sup\{\omega\cdot n + n\mid n<\omega\}$

We can replace each $\omega\cdot n + n$ by $\omega\cdot n+\omega=\omega\cdot (n+1)$, as it is another sequence of ordinal with the same limit (why?).

Now we have: $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega = \sup\{\omega\cdot (n+1)\mid n<\omega\} = \sup\{\omega\cdot n\mid n<\omega\} = \omega\cdot\omega=\omega^2$.

Now we also note that $\omega^2$ is *already* in Cantor normal form, and since it is unique we have that this is the CNF of $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega$.

The process for $(\omega+1)^\omega$ is essentially the same, and it yields the result $\omega^\omega$ as needed.

**Edit:** The $(\omega+1)^\omega$ case goes as follow:

$$
\begin{align*}
(\omega+1)^\omega &= \sup\{(\omega+1)^n\mid n<\omega\} &\\
 &= \sup\{(\omega+\omega)^n\mid n<\omega\} &\\ 
 &= \sup\{(\omega\cdot 2)^n\mid n<\omega\} &\\
 &= \sup\{\omega^n\cdot 2^n\mid n<\omega\} &\\
 &=\sup\{\omega^n\cdot\omega\mid n<\omega\} &\\  
 &= \sup\{\omega^{n+1}\mid n<\omega\}\\
 &=\omega^\omega
\end{align*}
$$

I am leaving it up to you to justify the transitions between the chosen sequences of ordinals.

**Edit II:** I'm adding the information from the comment, and a different proof for the above edit, based on that.

By exponentiation and multiplication laws we have $(\omega+1)^2=(\omega+1)\cdot(\omega+1) = (\omega+1)\cdot\omega+\omega+1 = \omega^2 + \omega + 1$, which is in CNF, as needed.

Based on that, we show that $(\omega+1)^\omega = \omega^\omega$:

$(\omega+1)^\omega = (\omega+1)^{2\cdot\omega} = ((\omega+1)^2)^\omega = (\omega^2+\omega+1)^\omega$.

We replace $\omega^2+\omega+1$ by $\omega^3$ which is a bigger ordinal, now we have $(\omega^3)^\omega = \omega^\omega$.

As before, I leave the justification of this replacement to you, essentially showing that $(\omega^2+\omega+1)^n$ has the same limit as $(\omega^3)^\omega$.

**A key note:** As I said at the beginning, the key issue is that at limit stages we take the supremum of a sequence of ordinals, and we can choose different sequences as we like, and we just need to prove that both the sequences would have the same limit.

Using "sandwich" arguments usually works - in fact by that we have it even simpler, 
$$\omega^\omega \le (\omega+1)^\omega \le (\omega^2)^\omega = \omega^{2\cdot\omega} = \omega^\omega$$

Comment: thank you i understand the explaination of the first one, but I am a little confused how w^w is considered the same as w^2? can you elaborate or maybe show the example ?

Comment: @Aaron: I have added information as per your request.

Comment: thank you, just wondering if you can give me the same help with writing (w+1)^2 in CNF

Comment: i am confused, so (w+1)^2 and (w+1)w are the same thing?

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry. They are different ordinals, of course. (I deleted the wrong comment). However $(\omega+1)^2=(\omega+1)\cdot(\omega+1) = (\omega+1)\cdot\omega+(\omega+1) = \omega^2+\omega+1$, as the the equality $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^2$ we have proven above.

Comment: @AsafKaragila how does $(\omega +1)\omega=\omega ^2$ settle with the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340332/bringing-ordinals-to-standard-polynomial-form) where $(\omega +2)\omega=\omega ^2+2$?