# Transfinite Sets & The Countability of The Primes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $0\in\mathbb{N}$
  and let the set $\mathbb{P}$
  be the set of all primes. Since, $\mathbb{P}\subset\mathbb{N}$
  there is a natural order on $\mathbb{P}$. So, we can define a function $f:\mathbb{P}\to\mathbb{N}$
  by the rule $p_{i}\overset{f}{\to}i$
  where $i\in\mathbb{N}$
  is the ordinal number of the $i$
 th prime in $\mathbb{P}$
 . Clearly $f$
  is a bijection, so there are countably many primes.

Now, from everything I have read I have concluded that $\omega=\mathbb{N}=\aleph_{0}$
 . So could we write the set of primes $\mathbb{P}=\{p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{\omega}\}$
 ? When I look at the set of primes in this manner it seems as if the primes are bounded above by the ordinal number $\omega+1$
 , is this true? Also since $\omega=\mathbb{N}$
  do there exist any primes in say $\omega+1$
 ?

Comment: No, if you mean to enumerate the primes in increasing order: there is no largest prime. Similarly, it is not true that $\Bbb Z^+=\{1,2,\ldots,\omega\}$: $\omega$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In the set theory book  I am reading it defines natural numbers like $3=\{1,2,3\}$ then it talks about a set $\omega=\mathbb{N}$ so is $\omega\in \omega$?

Comment: No, $\omega\notin\omega$. And if $3$ is being defined as $\{1,2,3\}$, they’re making a mistake: $3=\{0,1,2\}$ when this approach is used.

Comment: In general, every ordinal is equal to the set of all (strictly) lesser ordinals.  So the first infinite ordinal, $\omega$, is equal to the set of all finite ordinals $0,1,2,\ldots$, up to but not including $\omega$ itself.

Comment: I wonder who voted to close this question as "not about mathematics"?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry about that, they did define it as $3=\{0,1,2\}$. I now see why $\omega \notin \omega$, but $\omega \in \omega+1$, right? Also is subtraction defined for transfinite arithmetic?

Comment: I am just really confused about transfinite sets, I don't mean to offend anyone in the mathematics community.

Comment: Yes, $\omega\in\omega+1$; in fact $$\omega+1=\omega\cup\{\omega}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,\omega\}\;.$$ Many people find transfinite sets a bit confusing, especially at first, and honest confusion shouldn’t give offense, so for goodness’ sake go ahead and ask questions when you’re confused.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks Alot! I appreciate your patience. What about if we took $\omega \cup \{\sqrt{2}\}$ would this also be equal to $\omega+1$?

Comment: No, because $\sqrt2\ne\omega$; there is, however, a fairly natural bijection between $\omega\cup\{\sqrt2\}$ and $\omega+1$: map each $n\in\omega$ to itself, and map $\sqrt2$ to the element $\omega$ of $\omega+1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Cool! I have a lot more questions if you don't mind. The first uncountable set is $\aleph_1=\omega_1$ right? Then, $\omega_1$ comes after what? there is $\omega,\omega+1,...,\omega 2,...,\omega^2,...,\epsilon_0,...\epsilon_{\omega}$ and then comes $\omega_1$?

Comment: @JimmyJackson: Many, many more ordinals than it’s possible to name. For starters, $\epsilon_\alpha$ is still countable as long as $\alpha$ is countable, so, for example, $\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}$ is countable. It takes a while to develop a feel for just what $\omega_1$ is like, and you develop it more by actually working with $\omega_1$ than by finding ways to look at it. If you’re interested in getting more of a handle on ordinals in general, you might try looking at [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form) for ordinals; ...

Comment: ... Asaf’s answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36856/cantor-normal-form-and-the-steps-taken) may also be helpful. There’s quite a bit on the net, though a lot of it is likely to be pretty heavy going.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! I think these two reading will hold me over for awhile. I will send a comment here, if I get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as there is no element of $\Bbb N$ that is $\omega$, there is no prime $p_{\omega}$  Each prime has a finite index, just as all natural numbers are finite.

Nothing you have said establishes that there are an infinite number of primes.  Without that we cannot say that $f$ is a bijection.  It is true, however.

Within the ordinals, it is true that $\Bbb P$ is bounded above by $\omega + 1$.  In the usual picture of the ordinals, all the naturals are elements of $\omega + 1$, so all the primes are in $\omega + 1$.  I don't know what use that is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is helpful for me to grasp the idea of transfinite sets.

Answer (score 2):

The primes can be enumerated in increasing order as $\{p_i : i < \omega\}$.
That is, there are $\omega$ many primes, and the $n$-th prime $p_n$ can be defined for every $n<\omega$.
 There is no $\omega$-th prime $p_\omega$, nor are $p_{\omega+1}$, $p_{\omega+2}$, *etc.* defined.  The reason for this is that all primes are natural numbers by definition.  One could try to define some infinite analogs of primes, but this seems unlikely to be interesting because multiplication of infinite cardinals is trivial: if $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals then their product $\kappa \cdot \lambda$ is just $\max(\kappa,\lambda)$.