# Bringing ordinals to standard polynomial form

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

By the definition of multiplication and addition of ordinals, the following rules follow-

Multiplication- $n\cdot\omega=\omega$ while $\omega\cdot n > \omega$

Addition- $n+\omega=\omega$ while $\omega + n >\omega$

Distribution- if $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are ordinals, $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$ but $(\beta+\gamma)\alpha\neq\beta\alpha+\gamma\alpha$ .

Having written those, I can bring certain ordinals to a polynomial form, this way I can compare them.

For example, $(2+\omega)(\omega+3)=\omega(\omega+3)=\omega^2+\omega\cdot 3$

But what do I do with $(\omega+2)(\omega+3)$? How do I bring this to a polynomial form? The first step I am allowed to do by the rules above is:

$(\omega+2)(\omega+3)=(\omega+2)\cdot\omega+(\omega+2)\cdot3$. I can't think of a way to simplfy it from here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are really the only rules you're given, then I don't see how to do it.

However, remember that $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is (intuitively) the ordinal gotten by replacing each element of $\beta$ by a copy of $\alpha$. So, e.g., $\omega\cdot 2=\omega+\omega$. So, for example, we have $$(\omega+2)\cdot 3=(\omega+2)+(\omega+2)+(\omega+2),$$ which can be simplified to $\omega\cdot 3+2$. $(\omega+2)\cdot\omega$ can be handled similarly.

---

EDIT: in fact, we can show that those rules aren't sufficient: consider the "silly ordinal product," $\circ$, given by $\alpha\circ\beta=\alpha\cdot \beta$ if $\alpha$ is finite, and $\alpha\circ\beta=\alpha\cdot\beta+1$ if $\alpha$ is infinite and $\beta\not=0$, and $\alpha\circ 0=0$. Then $\circ$ satisfies all the rules you've written, but of course gives a different value for e.g. $\omega\cdot 2$.

Comment: Did you mean $\omega$3+ 6? But this looks exactly like the distributive law that isn't always true, like I noted. How can $(\omega+2)\cdot\omega$ be handled? How can I write an infinite number of elements and add them? Again, I get to the wrong distributive property. Feels like cheating...

Comment: I did **not** mean $\omega3+6$, it's $\omega3+2$. The reason is associativity: $(\omega+2)+(\omega+2)+(\omega+2)=\omega+(2+\omega)+(2+\omega)+2=\omega+\omega + \omega +2=\omega 3+2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: So by the same method, $(\omega+2)\omega$ would be $\omega^2+2$. Correct?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it.

Comment: Last question- wouldn't it make more sense not break apart the $(\omega+2)(\omega+3)$ statement to $(\omega+2)\cdot\omega$ and $(\omega+2)\cdot3$ seperately, but instead calculate the original expression all together in the way you showed?

Comment: Yes, I would say so - but this depends on the person.